# Can a models values still be edited when the fields aren't available on a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm not familiar on how forms work.

**Example Scenario**

Lets say users can create surveys but after they are created cannot edit them but only add questions to them. This is done by using the edit action on the Survey.

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  belongs_to :user
end

# QuestionsController

def edit
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  @survey.questions.build
end

def update
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  @survey.update_attributes(params[:survey])
  redirect_to ...
end
```

Then the form should be:

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>
  # No surveys fields on this form!

  <% f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
    <%= render "question_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Now does this leave the Survey's values vulnerable or open to hacking even if I want the survey's fields to be unusable after creation?

What about in general? Can model values still be edited when their not on the form? What's the logic behind this and how would I know they couldn't?

Thanks, just a newbie trying to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those attributes can still be edited by submitting them as parameters to your form, even if you don't provide fields for them.

To protect against that, you can [protect the attributes explicitly](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_protected) (in later versions of Rails, this is the default). In your `Survey` model, add

```
attr_protected :name # or whatever other attributes that model has
```

This prevents mass assignments for those attributes, both for create and update. To allow creating, you'll have to assign those attributes explicitly in the `create` action of your `SurveyController`:

```
def create
  @survey = Survey.new # instead of Survey.new(params[:survey])
  @survey.name = params[:survey][:name]
  @survey.save 
  # etc
end
```

EDIT:

As blackbird07 points out, the better approach is to whitelist those attributes that you want to allow mass-assignment for, instead of the blacklist approach described here.

Comment: interesting, so the `attr_accessible` is just for convenience? For security it will be better for me to manually input what I want in the controller?

Comment: `attr_accessible` is the whitelist approach - when you use it, all attributes that are *not* included are protected. `attr_protected` is the exact opposite.

Answer (score 1):

In short: Yes, they can be edited with a well-crafted POST request using either a tool like curl or by editing the HTML form with browser developer tools. The reason is that you use `update_attributes` for doing the update, which will update all attributes supplied in the params parameter. This is called mass-assignment.

It is recommended that you whitelist the attributes you want to be editable: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

Also, it is highly recommended that your read this article about ["Strong parameters: Dealing with mass assignment in the controller instead of the model"](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also protect against mass assignment by putting

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

in your config/application.rb

Now all atttrbitues must be explicitly labeled accessible. It does this by creating an empty whitelist of attributes for all models in your app.

Comment: Would it also be a good idea to do `attr_accessible # none` in my models for extra security?

Comment: Yes, it would be a good reminder that you already have your mass assignment handled.